# intellij idea wrong "Find Usages" behavior for javascript object properties

Tags: intellij-idea, intellij-14

I think best way to explain the problem would be first to look on this screen shot:

[image: look on the highlighted properties and find usages pane]

You can see that there are two javascript objects in the code: `object1` & `object2`.

Both have a property named `property`.

When I am trying to find the usages of the `object1.property`, in the results I am getting also usages of `object2.property`. Also, when I would try to "refactore->rename" it will rename the property name, it will rename both object1 and object2.

Why is that happen? How to solve this issue? I am using completely fresh install of IDEA 14 Ultimate (licensed version) with default settings. I created an empty project and put inside only 1 file and the problem still exists.

It seems like there is no smart algorithm that is being used for "Find Usages" in javascript files. The feeling is that is just look for text occurrences within the files. I want to believe that this is kind of project settings or other configuration issue that I still don't know how to fix.

Please help

[link to the gist](https://gist.github.com/artyil/9645667eb764a1091e3d) file

**an UPDATE after getting answer from JetBreans representative, just FYI :**
Netbeans get it right, snapshot of renaming a property of an object:
[image: Netbeans find usages javascript]

Answer (score 1):

No, this is not a configuration issue. "Find Usages" for JavaScript in IntelliJ IDEA is smarter than a plain text search, but it still can't correctly understand which particular method is being referenced in all cases. Your example is fairly simple, but it's not very representative of the way JS is used in practice, so getting this case right wasn't a priority for the team.

Comment: Thank you for the help. I assume this is official, since you are part of "the team"? Can you please explain more about was is considered a "representative way to use JS in practice" ? Will this "way" solve the problem?